# Highcharts switching off animation for column chart

Tags: javascript, animation, graph, highcharts, data-visualization

I'm drawing a column chart and it is updated everytime new data is received from a websocket. But everytime a chart is drawn you see the columns 'go up', that's getting a bit nauseating to see that everytime. I would rather the map be plotted to the new 'height'

I tried, but this gives me a 405 error:

```
            plotOptions: {
            column: {
                animation: false
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0

            }
        }
```

I can't see anything else in the documentation to suggest otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `,` after `animation: false`.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUQrF/2/)